# How to query for results recursively on the same table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table with two columns - ID and AlternateID. The AlternateID may itself have an AlternateID, also captured in the same table.

My objective is to construct a table where AlternateIDs with AlternateIDs resolve until they no longer have an AlternateID. How do I do this?

Here is some sample data

Source table looks like this

```
ID | AlternateID
-----------------
10 | 1
11 | 2
12 | 3
13 | 11
14 | 12
15 | 14
```

My final table should look like this

```
ID | FinalAlternateID
-----------------
10 | 1
11 | 2
12 | 3
13 | 2
14 | 3
15 | 3
```

Things tried so far

1. Wrote a recursive function that takes the id and calls itself. This
   kind of works but for the data set I am working on this approach is
   very very slow.
2. Attempted to write a recursive CTE, but I couldn't
   succeed, I was getting compile errors where the as soon as I add the recursive call, it wouldnt be recognized, not sure what the issue is.

Here is the code for the CTE (sorry, for some reason unable to format as code in Stack)

```
with FinalAlternateIDs (ID, AlternateID, Level) as
(
-- start with ones that dont have an AlternateID
select T1.ID, T1.AlternateID, 0 as Level 
from InitialAlternateIDs T1
        left join InitialAlternateIDs T2 on (T1.AlternateID = T2.ID)
where T2.ID is NULL
union all
-- combine it with rows that have AlternateIDs in current result set
-- (exclude ones that are already in the result set)
select T1.ID, T3.AlternateID, (Level + 1) as Level 
from InitialAlternateIDs T1
        left join FinalAlternateIDs T2 on (T1.ID = T2.ID)
        join FinalAlternateIDs T3 on (T1.AlternateID = T3.ID)
where T2.ID is NULL
)
select * 
from FinalAlternateIDs
```

Comment: why not include your recursive CTE code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, alternateid, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.id, t.alternateid, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.alternateid = t.id
     )
select cte.id, cte.alternateid
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by id) as maxlev
      from cte
     ) cte
where lev = maxlev;
```